# SiteDefinition and ContentBySearchWebPart

Tags: 2013, site-definition

I have custom templates for a ContentBySearchWebPart. I tries to add these templates and a page with ContentBySearchWebPart by module which is implemented into onet.xml. My issue is when the web part is provisioned, the `ItemTemplateId` and `RenderTemplateId` properties are set to default values. My settings are ignored. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the tile (~) needs to be xml escaped to be parsed correctly.
So:

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_TwoLines.js</property>'''
```

Should become:

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">&#126;sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_TwoLines.js</property>
```

As I found on http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/04/provisioning-content-search-web-part.html